# Index [data-attribute] within template literal using Array.prototype.map(callback, index)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Lets say I have an array of objects returned from a fetch to some api.
I am currently creating markup like this...

`var cardMarkup = objects.map(cardBuilder).join("");`

```
function cardBuilder(meeting){
  var template = `<div class="meeting">${meeting.organizer}</div>`
  return template
}
```

I would like to have an incremental index for each card that is built and spat out in cardMarkup. 
So I end up with DOM looking like this...

`<div class="meeting" data-index = 0 >${meeting.organizer}</div>` 
`<div class="meeting" data-index = 1 >${meeting.organizer}</div>` 
`<div class="meeting" data-index = 2 >${meeting.organizer}</div>`

My point is so that I can later query these card divs individually/specifically, because right now they all have the same class names. Maybe this problem needs a separate solution altogether, I am open to all suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for `map`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

You will see the second argument passed into the callback is the index so you just need to reference it and apply this as the data attribute.

```
function cardBuilder(meeting, index){
  var template = `<div class="meeting" data-index="${index}">${meeting.organizer}</div>`
  return template
}
```

Comment: thanks blake for the lightning response! I had suspected that was the case, didn't think I could pass index as an argument.

this is a screenshot showing it worked in chrome devtools!
http://prntscr.com/hwg8l1

Comment: @AkinHwan I'm glad it worked! If you feel like marking at as the correct answer, that would be awesome ;)